# How to pass component callback to children element in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I would like to wrap my current router by Layout with one MapBox and pass to children MapBox callback function:

```
  <Route path='/posts' component={PostsList} />
    <Route path="/posts/:id" component={Post} >
  </Route>
```

Currently to handle callback I repeat MapBox on two components:

```
export default class Post extends React.Component {
  mapMoved(map) {console.log('map moved', map)}
  render() {
    const {post, posts} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {post.title}
        <MapBox mapMoved={::this.mapMoved} posts={posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  post: state.post,
  posts: state.posts,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Post);

export default class PostsList extends React.Component {
  renderList() {
    const {posts} = this.props;
  }
  mapMoved(map) {console.log('map moved', map)}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {::this.renderList()}
        <MapBox mapMoved={::this.mapMoved} posts={this.props.posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostsList);
```

Desired routes wrapped by Layout:

```
<Route component={Layout}>
  <Route path='/posts' component={PostsList} />
    <Route path="/posts/:id" component={Post} >
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Desired Layout component:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  mapMoved(map) {}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children} //I would like to pass mapMoved callback here
        <MapBox mapMoved={::this.mapMoved} posts={this.props.posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

I'm using Redux, maybe should I pass somehow callback function trough it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass props to children like so

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  mapMoved(map) {}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children || <div />, {mapMoved: (map) => this.mapMoved(map)})} //I would like to pass mapMoved callback here
        <MapBox mapMoved={::this.mapMoved} posts={this.props.posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

Comment: can I pass it directly without binding it to `mapMoved(map) {}`?

Comment: how to handle mapMoved() in child component?

Comment: in the child component you'll have access to mapMoved via props i.e `this.props.mapMoved(map)`

Comment: I wanted to pass `mapMoved` callback function and handle it in children like own function instead of passing data through props and filtering them to catch right thing on each props change, I am interested only in one `mapMoved` event, how to cope with that?

Comment: ah so you want to share mapMoved between different components without passing it via props?

Comment: Yes, just pass `mapMoved` event to process it in different ways in each children. I spend a lot of time on it, but can't reach desired result.

Comment: could you explain a bit more about what `mapMoved` does, would be easier to help If I knew what `mapMoved ` needs access to